# How to form CGPoint array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, boxing

I want to get this structure:

```
CGPoint addLines1[] =
{
    CGPointMake(30.0, 150.0),
    CGPointMake(41.67, 145.19),
    CGPointMake(53.33, 103.25),
    CGPointMake(65.0, 131.67),
    CGPointMake(76.67, 106.11),
    CGPointMake(88.33, 110.20),
    CGPointMake(100.0, 111.54),
    CGPointMake(111.67, 112.13),
    CGPointMake(123.33, 115.66),
    CGPointMake(135.0, 123.7),
    CGPointMake(146.67, 125.53),
    CGPointMake(158.33, 115.1),
    CGPointMake(170.0, 69.38),
    CGPointMake(181.67, 112.47),
    CGPointMake(193.33, 65.1),
    CGPointMake(205.0, 103.33),
    CGPointMake(216.67, 92.6),
    CGPointMake(228.33, 54.76),
    CGPointMake(240.0, 79.66),
    CGPointMake(251.67, 53.81),
    CGPointMake(263.33, 56.81),
    CGPointMake(275.0, 88.19),
    CGPointMake(286.67, 74.81),
    CGPointMake(298.33, 28.1),
    CGPointMake(310, 20.0),
};
```

In order to make some calculations and draw data.

I have `CGPoint *lines = appDelegate.averageResponseTimePoints;`

How to make array `addLines[]` from `*lines`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

C arrays are not really arrays at run time, where they are just pointers to a contiguous block of objects of the same type. When you see `items[n]`, that's just syntactic sugar for `*(items+n)`.

In your example `addLines[1]` would be `*(lines+1)` and `addLines[0]` would be `*(lines+0)`, which is `*lines`. So, `addLines` is just `lines` without the pointer dereference. `*lines` is the first item in the array and `lines` is the whole array.

Arrays have some differences to pointers at compile time. For example, `sizeof(addLines)` would give you the size of the whole array.

Array-ness is lost as soon as you pass the array somewhere where it's size might be variable, but you can still use the subscript operator. For example:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define showsize( expr ) ( printf(#expr " = %zd\n", ( expr ) ) )

CGPoint *
pass_back(CGPoint points[4])
{
    showsize(sizeof(points));
    return points;
}

int
main(void)
{
    CGPoint square[] = {CGPointMake(-1.0,  1.0),
                        CGPointMake( 1.0,  1.0),
                        CGPointMake( 1.0, -1.0),
                        CGPointMake(-1.0, -1.0)};
    CGPoint* returned;
    int i;

    showsize(sizeof(CGPoint));
    showsize(sizeof(CGPoint*));
    showsize(sizeof(square));
    returned = pass_back(square);
    showsize(sizeof(returned));

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("returned[%d] = {%0.1f, %0.1f}\n", i, (float) returned[i].x,
                                                 (float) returned[i].y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs the following on my Mac:

```
sizeof(CGPoint) = 8
sizeof(CGPoint*) = 4
sizeof(square) = 32
sizeof(points) = 4
sizeof(returned) = 4
returned[0] = {-1.0, 1.0}
returned[1] = {1.0, 1.0}
returned[2] = {1.0, -1.0}
returned[3] = {-1.0, -1.0}
```

Here, `square` is the size of four `CGPoint`s, but once sent to the `pass_back` function, it's only the size of a pointer, because that's what it is. When the pointer comes back (and named `returned`) it can still be used like an array.

Note the magic number `4` in the loop. The pointer doesn't know the length of the array it's pointing to.

Arrays cannot be reassigned with the `=` operator. If you really must populate `addLines` with the points from `lines`, you can do that with something like the following:

```
memcpy(addLines, lines, sizeof(CGPoint) * numberOfPoints);
```

You'll have to get `numberOfPoints` from somewhere, and `addLines` will have to be large enough to handle those points. That's okay if the number of points is a constant, but it would be *bad* if the number of points can vary at run time, especially if the points come from the outside world (think arbitrary code execution).

I'd change `averageResponseTimePoints` to return an NSArray rather than a C-style array. You'll need to encapsulate the `CGPoint`s in objects - either your own object or `NSValue`s.

Here's an example of how you could write `averageResponseTimePoints`:

```
- (NSArray*) averageResponseTimePoints
{
    NSMutableArray* result = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
        NSValue* point = [NSValue value:points+i
                           withObjCType:@encode(CGPoint)];
        [result addObject:point];
    }

    return result;
}
```

If your code runs with CocoaTouch, you can use this to create the point value instead:

```
NSValue* point = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[i]];
```

To get the `CGPoint`s out of the array, you could write something like this:

```
for (NSValue* value in result) {
    NSPoint pt;
    [value getValue:&pt];
    NSLog(@"%f %f", pt.x, pt.y);
}
```

Or with CocoaTouch:

```
CGPoint pt = [value CGPointValue];
```

Comment: Consider difference between two methods: `valueWithCGPoint:` and `valueWithPointer:`. [Details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11106539/991816)

Comment: "C arrays are not really arrays at run time".  Yes they are - they're perfectly valid C arrays.  What you mean is that they are not NSArrays.

Comment: @northernman What Will means is that _“The C ‘runtime’ has no concept of an ‘array’— C arrays are language/compiler-level tricks, and only understood as pointers at runtime.”_  So no, at runtime they're not _‘perfectly valid C arrays’_, because in this respect C is hands-off at the point of runtime.

Comment: @northernman This distinction is more clear in comparison to languages that do have runtime representations of arrays— Objective-C's `NSArray`, C++'s STL `array`/`deque`/`list`/etc, Java `isArray()`-adhering types, C# `IsArray`-adhering types, JavaScript's `Array`, etc.

Comment: You are applying a "modern" definition of arrays.  I'll take one of the C inventors terminology as authoritative:  http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html#array

Answer (score 52):

For iOS:

Create array:

```
NSArray *myCGPointArray = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(30.0, 150.0)],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(41.67, 145.19)]];
```

Get 1st CGPoint object:

```
CGPoint myPoint = [myCGPointArray[0] CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
CGPoint A[10];
A[0] = CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0);
A[1] = CGPointMake(10.0, 12.0);
float x = A[1].y;
NSLog(@"%.0f", x);
```

It works. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

I tried Tibidabo's answer, and it didn't work for me.  It said [myCGPointArray objectAtIndex:0] was of type id, so I couldn't call CGPointValue on it.  hm.

this worked however:

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 6.6)],
                   [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(7.7, 8.8)],
                   nil];

NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint point = [val CGPointValue];
float X = point.x;
NSLog(@"cgpoint value is: %f", X);
```

or

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(20, 6.6)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(7.7, 8.8)],
                        nil];
float xCoordinate = [[points objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue].x;
```

I found it here: [How can I add CGPoint objects to an NSArray the easy way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899600/how-can-i-add-cgpoint-objects-to-an-nsarray-the-easy-way), posted by Jarret Hardie.

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem doing the next:

---

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myPoint]];
```

---

Thanks to [michael-jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2203705/michael-jensen) for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15603975/2835520)!