# Convert the NSValues to a CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cgpoint, nsvalue

I need to convert `NSValue`s from a dictionary to `CGPoint`.

Example: I have a dictionary with 2 items in it:

```
NSValue *p1 = [dict objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"];
NSValue *p2 = [dict objectForKey:@"LONGITUDE"];
```

When I try this, it gives an error

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake((CGFloat)p1;, (CGFloat)p2);
```

Comment: `CGPoint point = CGPointMake([p1 floatValue], [p2 floatValue])`? But why `NSValue`? Are you sure they are `NSValue` objects, `NSNumber` usually is enough?  Why not using already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772958/converting-a-cgpoint-to-nsvalue to store points?

Comment: @Larme - tried CGPoint point = CGPointMake([p1 floatValue], [p2 floatValue]).. did not work

Comment: `NSLog(@"Latitude Class :%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"] class])` that prints what exactly? I checked, NSValue doesn't have `floatValue`, `NSNumber` does. It shouldn't be a `NSValue`.

Comment: There‘s an extra semicolon in your statement‘s parameter list. But beyond that, you can‘t just cast an object address to get a float. You need to call a method on that object that will get that float from the object, like floatValue.